# PHP array_push index retention

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am looping through an array which itself contains array to find indexes of values 5 & 6.

Upon finding these indexes, I push the matched array, using array_push, into a another array. My application depends on maintaining the array indexes but array_push resets the keys to 0, 1, 2 etc rather than the matched 5, 6, 7 etc.

Comment: Can you please show a code snippet?

Comment: Instead of using `array_push($array, $new)`, can you do `$array[] = $new` or even `$array[$key] = $new` (depending on the `$key` you want)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling array_push you can add element this way:

```
$arr[5] = array("foo", "bar");
$arr[6] = array("red", "blue");
$arr[7] = array("123", "567");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that do or did I miss something?

```
$newArray = array();

foreach( $myArrays as $myArray ) 
  if( ($result = array_search(5, $myArray)) || ($result = array_search(6, $myArray))
    $newArray[$result] = $myArray[$result];
```